# Color of a multirow cell in table

Tags: tables

I have to color the first column of three rows called the Method box. I tried but still cannot get success.

**How I can align two tables horizontally in the ICCV template?**

**Code**

```
\begin{tabular}{l|cc}
\hline\thickhline
%\rowcolor{mygray}
\multirow{3}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}Method} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CIFAR-100} \\ \cline{2-3}  &
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Top-1} \\ \textbf{Error(\%)} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Top-5} \\ \textbf{Error(\%)} \end{tabular} 
\\
\hline \hline
Vanilla  &  23.67  \\ 
\hspace{0.5em}{+CMAAug}  & \textcolor{blue}{-} 
& \textcolor{blue}{-}
\\ %\hline
\thickhline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: If you would still like an answer to this, could you please edit your code to include a small example that we can compile please?

Answer (score 1):

- your question is not entirely clear, sorry ...
- you not provide any information about your document, so I decide to use `standalone` document class
- in your code fragment you should move multirow cell to the second row and then use negative number of spanned rows, for example as is done in the next MWE (based on your code fragment, but quite cleaned):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{boldline, makecell, multirow} % guessing ... what you should add to preamble

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{l |cc}
    \hlineB{1.25}
\cellcolor[gray]{0.9} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CIFAR-100}                 \\
    \cline{2-3}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}{Method}}
                & \bfseries\makecell{Top 1\\ Error (\%)}
                    &   \bfseries\makecell{Top 2\\ Error (\%)}  \\
    \hline
Vanilla         & 0.384
                    &                           \\
\quad+CMAAug    &   \textcolor{blue}{--} 
                    &   \textcolor{blue}{--}    \\
    \hlineB{1.25}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- but your table can be write with much shorter (and cleaner) code ... for example with use of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\SCfg[1]{\SetCell{fg=#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={l | *{2}{Q[c]} },
             cell{2}{2-Z} = {font=\bfseries},
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c, bg=yellow!30}  Method 
                &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} CIFAR-100
                    &                           \\
    \midrule
                &   {Top 1\\ Error (\%)}
                    &   {Top 2\\ Error (\%)}    \\
    \midrule
Vanilla         & 0.384
                    &                           \\
\quad+CMAAug    &   \SCfg{blue} -- 
                    &   \SCfg{blue} --          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]